# vba copy from cells to another sheet when value is yes

Tags: excel, vba, copy

So I have two sheets, one with info and one where the info should be copied too.

If DONE is marked yes, all the info in that row will be copied to the sheet called "FullpInfo2 (with a button). In the "template" on the picture. But I have no idea what to do now. Could someone just give me an idea how to continue this?

If I add a new row and giving it value "yes", it should rewrite the previous (Name, Drink, Food, Vehicle)

[image]

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet

    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("PersonalInfo")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("FullpInfo")


    For Each c In Source.Range("E2:E100")   ' Do 100 rows

        If c = "yes" Then


        Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)

            Target.Cells("B15").Value = Source.Cells("A").Value ' I dont know what to do here..

        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyYes()

    Dim cell As Range
    Dim Source As Worksheet, Target As Worksheet

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Source = .Worksheets("PersonalInfo")
        Set Target = .Worksheets("FullpInfo")
    End With

    With Target

        'Formatting
        Call Module1.Formatting(.Range("B3"), "Name", "Titles")
        Call Module1.Formatting(.Range("D3"), "Drink", "Titles")
        Call Module1.Formatting(.Range("B6"), "Food", "Titles")
        Call Module1.Formatting(.Range("D6"), "Vehicle", "Titles")

        For Each cell In Source.Range("E2:E100")

            If cell.Value = "yes" Then

                'Values
                Call Module1.Formatting(.Range("B4"), Source.Range("A" & cell.Row).Value, "Values")
                Call Module1.Formatting(.Range("D4"), Source.Range("C" & cell.Row).Value, "Values")
                Call Module1.Formatting(.Range("B7"), Source.Range("B" & cell.Row).Value, "Values")
                Call Module1.Formatting(.Range("D7"), Source.Range("D" & cell.Row).Value, "Values")

            End If

        Next cell

    End With

End Sub

Sub Formatting(ByVal rng As Range, str As String, strType As String)

    With rng
        .Value = str
        .Font.Bold = True
        If strType = "Values" Then
            .Font.Color = vbBlue
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry,  I forgot saying that it should work if I create another line aswell. But I got up "Error 424, Object required"

Comment: The code works if you add lines. Have in mind that code is case sensitive checking for "yes". Where did you get the error?

Comment: Yeah, Im stupid. So tired, forgot Option Explicit and change Module1.. It works now, but it do create a new line for every time I press button. Is it possible to replace the current "Name, Drink, Food and Vehicle" in FullpInfo? Just replace, not creating new line :)

Comment: in order to make it clear. each line should replace the old one? for example all Names will be placed in cell B4, Drinks in D4, Foods in B7 & Vehicles in cell D7?

Comment: Yeah exactly :)

Comment: But there will only be one row with yes, not more than one.

Comment: try the new answer

Comment: Glad to hear that answer helps!